# Как расширить класс Convert Своими функциями?

Tags: c#

Собственно допустим у меня есть некоторые классы

```
public class Model
{
  int id {get;set;}
  string Name {get;set;}
  override string ToString()
     {
        return id+";"+Name;
     }
}

public class LongModel
{
  int id {get;set;}
  string Name {get;set;}
  bool active {get;set;}
   override string ToString()
     {
        return id+";"+Name+";"+active;
     }
}
```

Сейчас у меня есть класс для конвертирования

```
public static class ModelConverter
{
  public static Model ToModel(this LongModel LM)
   {
     return new Model{id=LM.id, Name =LM.Name};
   }
    // конвертирование из строки самой модели, конвертирование из строки длинной модели и пр.
}
```

Можно ли как-то сделать так что-бы эти методы можно было вызывать как `Convert.ToModel(longModel)`
при этом что-бы не пришлось прописывать для каждого случая полный путь:

```
 System.Convert.Toint32(...);
 Myproject.Convert.ToModel(longModel);
```

Можно ли вообще такого добиться?
**N.B.** Полный путь приходиться прописывать из-за конфликта имен, по сути вопрос, задан с целю избежать конфликта имен, но использовать всегда одно наименование Convert.

Comment: если сейчас функции организованы как расширения, почему не использовать их как расширения: `longModel.ToModel()`, зачем нужно пытаться добавлять их в `Convert`?

Comment: @Grundy потому что есть еще получение string, и ее обратная конвертация.

Comment: @Grundy  а больше это даже мое любопытство, просто периодически встречается функциональность, которую хочется по логике добавить в существующие классы, но сами классы находятся в системной библиотеке, по сути, не исправляя класс хочется его расширить.

Comment: С точки зрения организации кода и операций над бизнес-объектами конвертация простых типов и конвертация моделей - разные виды ответственностей, таким образом результат, что вы хотите получить, как минимум нарушает [SRP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)

Comment: С точки зрения гибкости кода, статические классы не могут быть заменены другими реализациями в рантайме, что делает код менее гибким. Мало того, клиент такого класса должен иметь ссылку на сборку, где этот класс находится. И в добавок, клиент не может декларировать зависимость от подобного класса в конструкторе, что противоречит по сути [DI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: Ну и в догонку, основываясь на том, что я написал выше, использование клиентом статического класса, который содержит бизнес-логику, сильно усложняет модульное тестирование, так как невозможно заменить вызовы статических методов альтернативными реализациями (например, заглушкой)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не сможете добавить методы в уже существующий класс `Convert`, он не спроектирован с учётом возможного расширения. Но можно включить его функциональность в ваш класс. Для этого внесём в `Myproject.Convert` все методы из `System.Convert`!

Разумеется, делать это вручную неправильно, нам на помощь придёт кодогенерация. Напишем вспомогательный проект:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

// ...

static string Stringify(Type t) => t.FullName;
static string Stringify(IEnumerable<Type> tl) =>
    string.Join(", ", tl.Select(Stringify));
static string Stringify(ParameterInfo pi)
{
    if (pi.IsIn || pi.ParameterType.IsByRef || pi.HasDefaultValue)
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    return $"{Stringify(pi.ParameterType)} {pi.Name}";
}
static string Stringify(IEnumerable<ParameterInfo> pl) =>
    string.Join(", ", pl.Select(Stringify));
static string StringifyNames(IEnumerable<ParameterInfo> pl) =>
    string.Join(", ", pl.Select(p => p.Name));

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var methods = typeof(Convert) .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
    using (var outf = File.CreateText("Convert.proxy.cs"))
    {
        outf.WriteLine("using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;");
        outf.WriteLine();
        outf.WriteLine("namespace MyProject");
        outf.WriteLine("{");

        outf.WriteLine("    static partial class Convert");
        outf.WriteLine("    {");
        outf.WriteLine();

        foreach (var method in methods)
        {
            outf.WriteLine("        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]");
            outf.Write($"        public static {method.ReturnType.FullName} {method.Name}");
            if (method.IsGenericMethodDefinition)
                outf.Write($"<{Stringify(method.GetGenericArguments())}>");
            var parameters = method.GetParameters();
            outf.WriteLine($"({Stringify(parameters)}) => " +
                $"System.Convert.{method.Name}({StringifyNames(parameters)});");
            outf.WriteLine();
        }

        outf.WriteLine("    }");

        outf.WriteLine("}");
    }
}
```

Этот код сгенерирует файл `Convert.proxy.cs`, который вы подключите к основному проекту:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace MyProject
{
    static partial class Convert
    {

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public static System.TypeCode GetTypeCode(System.Object value) => System.Convert.GetTypeCode(value);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public static System.Boolean IsDBNull(System.Object value) => System.Convert.IsDBNull(value);
```

и. т. д.

Поскольку класс объявлен как `partial`, в него можно добавлять функции, не редактируя сгенерированный текст. Например, дополнительно в другом файле можно написать:

```
namespace MyProject
{
    static partial class Convert // добавляем методы в класс Convert
    {
        public static Model ToModel(LongModel LM)
        {
            return new Model { id = LM.id, Name = LM.Name };
        }
    }
    // и т. д.
}
```

Всё, теперь везде можно использовать `MyProject.Convert`.

Comment: как то жестко :)

Comment: @tym32167: Зато дёшево, надёжно и практично (ц)

Comment: дешево - согласен, но вот надежность и практичность вызывает вопросы )

Comment: @tym32167: Чтобы было надёжнее, нужно подключить через T4 на случай, если вдруг в новой версии фреймворка `Convert` проапдейтят. А в чём непрактичность? Слишком много возни? Ну да, автору вопроса хочется странного, а странного можно достичь лишь странными методами.

Comment: Ну, непрактичность больше относится к самому заданию, а не способу, как вы его решили. Мне кажется сомнительным смешивать логику конвертации простых типов данных с конвертацией моделей - это как то не SOLID'но

Comment: @tym32167: Ну это да, кстати, смешивать Convert.ToInt32 и конвертацию модельных классов не комильфо. Напишите об этом коммент, может, кто-нибудь прочитает и проникнется.

Comment: может и проникнется, отписал

Comment: @tym32167: Спасибо! Плюсанул.

Answer (score 3):

Расширять статические классы нельзя.

Однако, в вашем случае, возможно, удобнее будет использовать операторы приведения?
Например, у меня есть два класса точек - первый хранит x и y в int, а второй в byte. В любом из этих классов можно объявить операторы приведения к другому классу. Выглядеть это будет так:

```
public static implicit operator Point2Int(Point2Byte bytePoint)
{
    return new Point2Int(bytePoint.X, bytePoint.Y);
}

public static explicit operator Point2Byte(Point2Int bytePoint)
{
    return new Point2Byte((byte)bytePoint.X, (byte)bytePoint.Y);
}
```

`implicit` - говорит, что это приведение будет осуществляться "тихо", т.е. не нужно осуществлять его явно, а `explicit`, что для него потребуется явное указание необходимости приведения.

Вот пример использования:

```
//создали новый Point2Int
var pointInt = new Point2Int(1, 1); 

//т.к. приведение к Point2Byte explicit - требуется указать преобразование явно
Point2Byte pointByte = (Point2Byte)pointInt; 

//обратное приведение implicit - поэтому ничего указывать не нужно        
pointInt = pointByte;
```

`explicit` стоит использовать там, где возможна потеря данных (в моём примере int больше байта и при приведении могут потеряться значения, если X, например будет равен 400).
`implicit` можно использовать, если потеря невозможна (в моём случае byte спокойно превратится в int)

Comment: статически класс приведен как пример, того что хочется получить, по сути проблема в том что я конвертирую расширенную модель, или строку 9если она приведена в нужном формате в узкую модель, возможно и наоборот, но при этом мне нужно создать класс `ModelConverter`, хотя очень хочется назвать его просто `Converter`, но если я это сделаю, то далее мне нужно явно указывать какой конвертер я хочу получить, что не хочется делать.

Comment: @Monomax, я показал вам пример, как можно сделать это без класса Convert вообще) но по комментарию сейчас немного запутался, что вы хотите получить